# Fixing location of mediaplayer in landscape and portrait mode in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, media-player, screen-rotation

I have created a mediaplayer in xcode with a caption below the video. I am having issues with the layout when the device rotates to landscape mode. I implemented a changedView method that moves the mediaplayer when the device rotates. This works great if you start in portrait mode and then rotate the device. However, when you are in portrait mode and segue to the screen with the mediaplayer, it does not not move to the right location.
I implement the method in the viewdidload method, but that didn't fix the issue. How do I get it to be in the right location in landscape mode when I navigate to the page while already in landscape?

my code for the view controller containing the media player:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self changedView];

self.title =@"Catalase";
[self.cAidButton setTitle:@"Identification Flowchart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSURL* catalaseurl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"example.com"];     
catalaseplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:catalaseurl];  
[catalaseplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 214, 674, 481)];   
[self.view addSubview:catalaseplayer.view];

//additional customization
catalaseplayer.fullscreen = YES;
catalaseplayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
catalaseplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
}
-(void)changedView{
    UIInterfaceOrientation theOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if(theOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || theOrientation ==      UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

      [catalaseplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 214, 674, 481)];
  }
  else{
           [catalaseplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(152, 95, 721, 493)];
    }

}
    -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation   {
    [self changedView];
    }
```